# ¿Por qué Django me da el error "The empty path didn't match any of these"?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Estoy aprendiendo django y no se mucho lo que estoy haciendo pero este es el error al cargarlo en el navegador.

```
Page not found (404)
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in Proyecto1.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
saludo2/

The empty path didn't match any of these.
```

el codigo en el ide:

```
Views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse

def saludo2(request):
 return HttpResponse("hi everyone")
```

Views.py asi se llama la carpeta en donde esta este codigo.
siguiente carpeta

```
urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from Proyecto1.Views import saludo2

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('saludo2/',saludo2),
]
```

No sé qué estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 2):

Parece que estas haciendo la peticion a la raiz `/` pero en tus urls tinenes las rutas `/admin` y `/saludo2`. Navega a `localhost:8000/saludo2`

Answer (score 1):

Te falta solamente añadir la url saludo2 http://localhost:8000/saludo2/ que es una de las funciones que añadiste en el views , otra cosa que puede que no hallas hecho el comando python manage.py runserver en la carpeta donde lo contienes

Answer (score 1):

Estás visitando la dirección `http://localhost:8000`/, es decir la página '/' o raíz, pero no creaste la ruta correspondiente en `Views.py`

Por lo que expones, en el archivo `Views.py` ya creaste 2 rutas para las páginas "admin" y "saludo2", te falta "/"